# How to return thenable from wrapped generator function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, co

I have such a code in my project:

```
co(function *asyncFn() {
    let browser = yield someAsyncOperation();
    return browser;
}).then(browser => browser.exit());
```

As expected, this doesn't work since browser object has method `then`. I wonder if there are any ways to return `thenable` object from wrapped generator function. (or probably some other libraries rather than `co` for wrapping generators which support such cases).

Answer (score 0):

`co` accepts a generator and returns a Promise returning function, it doesn't call it.

```
const fn = co(function* asyncFn() { ... })

fn().then(() => browser.exit());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my example a generator function returns browser object, which is thenable, and it breaks things as far as I don't want `browser.then` to be called.